# Orden de evaluación expresión en Haskell

Tags: haskell, programación-funcional

estoy empezando con Haskell y tengo una duda bastante básica. No logro entender el orden de evaluación de la siguiente expresión:

```
((min 8).(max 2)) 5
```

Cuando lo ejecuto, me devuelve 5. Según la explicación que estoy leyendo, primero aplica la función max con 2 y 5, y luego min con 8 y 5 (El resultado de la anterior función). 
Pero como yo lo entiendo, usa las funciones min y max con un único argumento (Cosa que tengo entendido no se puede hacer con éstas) y luego compone ambas.

Alguien me podría explicar en que me estoy equivocando? Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1):

Al hacer:

```
(min 8)
```

Se aplica parcialmente `min`. El resultado es una función que recibe un entero
y devuelve el menor entre 8 y ese entero. Pasa algo similar con `(max 2)`.

Luego con:

```
((min 8).(max 2))
```

Se componen las dos funciones aplicadas parcialmente y el resultado es equivalente a:

```
\x -> (min 8) ((max 2) x)
```

Es decir, a una función que recibe un entero `x`, le aplica `(max 2)` y al resultado
también le aplica `(min 8)`.